# Wordpress rewrite .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, apache

I'm trying to add a `.htaccess` file so Wordpress can use a custom permalink.

I've added the following script to my `root`, which is located in `/web`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Although I've added the `.htaccess` file with this to the `root`, it still doesn't seem to work.

Am I missing something out?

Comment: is mod_rewrite.c enabled on your server?

Comment: How can I check if it is?

Comment: Look for `mod_rewrite` in `httpd.conf`. If it's present make sure it's not commented out (has a `#` at the begining).

Comment: Create a php file with `phpinfo()` see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php

Answer (score 1):

Here is a checklist for you

1. Ensure `mod_rewrite` is enabled
2. If using Fedora, SuSE, or CentOS ensure that `selinux` is configured
3. Ensure that `AllowOverride` is set to `All` in `httpd.conf`

Answer (score 0):

The one that we use on our site looks like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

The BEGIN and END WordPress look like comments to me, but maybe they are needed by someone along the way.  Also, on our site, the .htaccess is permissions 644 (chmod 644 .htaccess) and is owned by apache.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing the last RewriteRule and closing tag.
**RewriteRule . /index.php [L]** and the closing **`</IfModule>`** tag.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>
```

Once you have added this in, **go to the permalinks** page in the admin area. Loading this page will refresh your permalinks. After that you should be all set.